# Is there a better way in reversetransform a non reversable string

Tags: symfony

I have this class:

```
class UserToFullName implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function reverseTransform($userfullname)
    {
        //??
    }

    public function transform($user)
    {
       return $user->getFullName();
    }
}
```

$user->getFullName() is a function that formulates the full name of the user

this is really hard to reverse transform cause the full name may result to many user (if they have identical full name)

Is there a better way on resolving this problem?

Comment: If you could have many users it is not possible or so return always the first.

Comment: I think - no isn't. You have to create compound form type with user full name and unique user identificator, instead of simple string value with name.